# Save file to OneDrive for buisness/Office365

Tags: php, web-applications, onedrive

So the scenario is the following:
User has connected to a datasource from where data is fetched on a scheduled basis.
Data is to be stored in the onedrive edition the users has - can be professional or onedrive bisness/office365.

so the idea is move data from data provider to data store (Onedrive personal/Business) on a scheduled basis by cron.

I managed this for personal however for business it only works on my own domain - if a customer signs up and want's to connect his/her office365 it fails.

Q1  what's the best api lib to use for PHP?
Q2 is there any diffference other than the sign-in

br,
Ditlev

If there's an expert that is willing t olend me some tim eit would be much aprreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the token by passing this url->

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=your-redirect-url&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&client_secret=

get the accesstoken using the code by POST method
url:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token/
data to post: client_id=&code="code you got from previous request"&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&client_secret=&scope=Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, Web.Manage&content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

get the token from the array. this your authentication token.

Upload file to onedrive ->

you need to upload file using put method.

url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/foldername/filename:/content

pass this header: $headers = array( 
                        'Content-Type: application/text',
                        "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
                        "Pragma: no-cache", 
                        "Authorization: bearer ".$token
                );

and pass the data from the file by file_get_contents.

Comment: you should give app permission from your apps